# How to insert hyphen "-" after 4 digits automatically in TextBox in html5?

Tags: html, regex, forms, validation, autofill

I have made validation in input field in html5 to get this format 03xx-xxxxxxx.

```
pattern="03\d{2}-\d{7}"
```

Now I want to add this hyphen symbol automatically after fourth digit.How to do that?

Answer (score 4):

I must advice you against this type of input edit since it's usually frustrating when you need to edit typos.

Also I have no idea of the issues related to accessibility.

The [input pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation#Validating_against_a_regular_expression) only checks the data on submit, so it's not what you are looking for.

That said, here's one possible solution in JS:

```js
// select the input element
var i = document.querySelector('input.hyphen');
// number of charatcers before the hyphen
var n = 4;
// run this function everytime the user release a key
i.addEventListener('keyup', function (event) { 
  // if there are more then n digits
  if (i.value.length > n) {
    // save the carret position
    var s = i.selectionStart;
    // remove all dashes
    var t = i.value.replace(/-/g, '');
    // beginning string with n digits
    var b = t.substr(0, n);
    // end string with what's left (maxLength)
    var e = t.substr(n);
    // join then with a dash
    i.value = [b, e].join('-');
    // if the caret was before the dash put it back to the saved position
    if (s <= n) i.setSelectionRange(s, s);
    // if the caret was next to the dash put it after
    if (s == n+1) i.setSelectionRange(s+1, s+1);
  }
});
```

```html
<input class="hyphen" placeholder="0000-0000000" maxlength="12">
```

Comment: This is java script. Right?

Comment: Code is working properly according to requirements, but I have no idea which language is this.

Comment: Yes it's javascript, you asked for an html5 solution, right? You won't find any other language that works directly with the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

> I have made validation in input field in html5 to get this format 03xx-xxxxxxx.

One alternative approach (without javascript) is to use three `<input />` fields.

**Working Example:**

```css
#country,
#region {
width: 16px;
}

#local {
width: 56px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="country" value="03" readonly />
<input type="text" id="region" pattern="[0-9]{2}" placeholder="88" />
-
<input type="text" id="local" pattern="[0-9]{7}" placeholder="8888888"/>
```